# Как сосчитать процент на ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Господа, мне нужно сосчитать определенный процент от определенного числа, например, 6% от 100. Пробовал делать так. Делил число на 100, и умножал на процент, но получался неверный результат, когда число меньше 100. Вот как это можно посчитать?

Comment: Операции над целыми числами? Если да, то сначала умножьте число на процент, а затем разделите на 100. Ошибка будет меньше.

Comment: Вы наверное применяли обычное целочисленное деление? Надо использовать операции над переменной с плавающей запятой. Например, почитать об арифметическом сопроцессоре.

Comment: В добавление к комментарию @mikillskegg. А если сопроцессора нет (не x86, до 486sx, или до 386dx без сопроцессора), то воспользоваться библиотекой для операций с плавающей запятой.

Comment: @mikillskegg сопроцессор, конечно, хорошо, но не в студенческой лабе

@alexlz да, целые числа. Спасибо за ответ, ваш метод сработал. Дробную часть, я думаю, можно опустить

Comment: Кстати, после деления на 100 (инструкция idivl) дробная часть окажется в регистре %edx. Можете сразу использовать.

Comment: Тег ассемблер надо распилить на несколько, и запретить использование просто «ассемблер». Во избежание. Может у него arm или mips.

Comment: @drdaeman в нашей жизни ассемблер для mips -- ну совсем экзотика. А вот всякие 8- и 16-битные микроконтроллеры -- дело другое.